# Two sets of curly braces using lambda functions?

Tags: c++, lambda

I am wondering if someone could help me understand the following syntax snippet, specifically sections 1 and 2 (focusing on the two sets of curly brackets). Is it related to lamda function? If so, how?

```
void Logger::LogContentionAndAllocations() {
    // 1
    LogDetail([&](AsyncDetail& detail) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(tls_loggers_registerd_mutex_);
            for (auto tls_logger : tls_loggers_registerd_) {
                CollectTlsLoggerStats(tls_logger);
            }
        }
        //2.
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(tls_logger_orphans_mutex_);
            for (auto& orphan : tls_logger_orphans_) {
                CollectTlsLoggerStats(orphan.get());
            }
        }

        detail("Log Contention Counters:");
        detail(std::to_string(swap_request_slots_retry_count_) + " : swap_request_slots_retry_count");
        detail(std::to_string(swap_request_slots_retry_retry_count_) + " : swap_request_slots_retry_retry_count");
        detail(std::to_string(swap_request_slots_retry_reencounter_count_) + " : swap_request_slots_retry_reencounter_count");
        detail(std::to_string(start_reading_entries_retry_count_) + " : start_reading_entries_retry_count");
        detail(std::to_string(tls_total_log_cas_fail_count_) + " : tls_total_log_cas_fail_count");
        detail(std::to_string(tls_total_swap_buffers_slot_retry_count_) + " : tls_total_swap_buffers_slot_retry_count");

        swap_request_slots_retry_count_ = 0;
        swap_request_slots_retry_retry_count_ = 0;

        swap_request_slots_retry_reencounter_count_ = 0;
        start_reading_entries_retry_count_ = 0;
        tls_total_log_cas_fail_count_ = 0;

        tls_total_swap_buffers_slot_retry_count_ = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: **Obviously**, the purpose of the internal curly braces is to define a scope for `unique_lock`.  Same as it would be in a regular function.

Answer (score 2):

They're part of a lambda, yes. But all they're doing is creating their own scope. That is, after all, the purpose of curly braces in C++. More specifically, curly braces allow you to create a compound statement, and that compound statement will have its own local scope.

Answer (score 0):

The extra curly braces are simply being used to create additional [scope blocks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) to limit the lifetime of the `std::unique_lock` objects.  The objects are destructed, releasing their locks, when they go out of scope.

```
[&](AsyncDetail& detail) {
    { // <-- new scope created here
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(tls_loggers_registerd_mutex_);
        for (auto tls_logger : tls_loggers_registerd_) {
            CollectTlsLoggerStats(tls_logger);
        }
    } // <-- lock destroyed here
    //2.
    { // <-- new scope created here
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(tls_logger_orphans_mutex_);
        for (auto& orphan : tls_logger_orphans_) {
            CollectTlsLoggerStats(orphan.get());
        }
    } // <-- lock destroyed here

    ...
}
```

This is no different than the curly braces used for function bodies, `if` statements, loops, etc. Curly braces can be used to create new scopes, and scopes can be nested.